# Custom UIView performance

Tags: ios, swift, performance, uiview

I make custom UIView and do all in `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` method. Also there I want to add new view by calling `self.addSubView` method, with adding constraints and gesture recognizers.

I think about performance, is it ok to do that all stuff in `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` method.

Thanks.

Comment: Why have you create 3 identical threads? Bug or what? :) Goodluck with ur question tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it ok to do that all stuff in `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` method

Absolutely not. This has nothing to do with performance; it has to do with what `draw` means. It means *draw*. The only thing you should ever do in `draw` is give drawing commands so as to draw into the graphics context that has been pushed for you.

Another problem is that `draw` can be called many many times over the lifetime of a view, but adding constraints and gesture recognizers is something you only want to do once.

If you want to add constraints and gesture recognizers, do it an appropriate time, like when the view gets placed into its superview, or when layout is about to happen.

Comment: I don’t think he is going to add gesture recognizers or other stuff in `draw`

Comment: @Zich I think that’s exactly what he is going to do. Wrongly.

Comment: if he is going to add irrelevant codes there, I am completely agree with you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So I need to move adding gesture recognizers in another place (which is better one), but creating view and adding constraints is ok, right?

Comment: Creating constraints also should not be there, check `layoutSubViews`

Answer (score 1):

Custom drawing in an overrided `draw` method does not create a performance issue per se. However implementing a sloppy draw method will cause that.

If you are adding **just** drawing codes there and you are doing it with best possible practice. I believe you are good to go.